# Generic way to deal with same function but different enums that implements the same interface

Tags: java, enums

I have a list of `enums` that implements the same interface, for example:

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    ABC(TABLE_NAME),
    XYZ(TABLE_NAME);
    ...

    private final String tableName;


    MyEnum(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }
}
```

`MyInterface` would be something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
   String getTableName();
}
```

From all `enum` I have (let's say `MyEnum`, `MyEnum2`, `MyEnum3` and so on), I have to to the same thing, which is to read table names and sort them. Something like:

```
public static List<String> getHeader() {
    List<String> header = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyEnum a: MyEnum.values()) {
        header.add(a.getTableName());
    }
    Collections.sort(header);
    return header;
}
```

I want to convert this method to a generic one so I can pass all `enum` to the same function:

```
for (MyEnum a: MyEnum.values()) {
```

And avoid having `MyEnum` hardcoded in there and multiple copies of the same function do to the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share `MyInterface` as well please?

Comment: absolutely @WarrenFaith! Added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer from @JAsgarov a bit too unreadable and it limits it to enums instead of using the interface that already exists.

My solution would look like this: introduce a `getValues()` function in your interface and you are kind of done. You can now pass any enum value or instance of the interface to the function.

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    ABC(TABLE_NAME),
    XYZ(TABLE_NAME);

    private final String tableName;

    MyEnum(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public MyInterface[] getValues() {
        return values();
    }
}

public static List<String> getHeader(MyInterface interface) {
    List<String> header = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyInterface a : interface.getValues()) {
        header.add(a.getTableName());
    }
    Collections.sort(header);
    return header;
}

public interface MyInterface {
    String getTableName();

    MyInterface[] getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> List<String> getHeader(Class<T> enumType) {
    List<String> header = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T a: enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
        header.add(a.getTableName());
    }
    Collections.sort(header);
    return header;
}
```

So as you can see first you are defining the type that extends both and enum and the interface:

`<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface>` //this goes before return type and is defined for the scope of the method

We also need the enum class to iterate over values and we get that as a parameter in `Class<T> enumType`

rest is same as you had it